# Should I initialize objects using strings or property names or does it even matter?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there's any difference between this (property name initializer):

```
var buffalo = {
    word:"buffalo"
}
```

and this (string initializer):

```
var cow = {
    "word":"cow"
}
```

There seems to be no real difference that I can tell. Is there a specific reason to use one or the other? Or is it just a matter of preference?

Both variables can be accessed using dot syntax or brackets:

```
alert(buffalo.word+", "+cow.word);      // buffalo, cow
alert(buffalo["word"]+", "+cow["word"]);// buffalo, cow
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It really doesn't matter honestly.

Comment: If anyone can direct me to an explanation of why there are two methods, that would be great. Is there a performance benefit to using one over the other? Best practice? Anything?

Comment: Many coding styles prefer non-quoted keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no technical difference. But in terms of readability and maintainability, the `.` notation is better, because the `[]` notation is already used for arrays.

The only reason to use the `[]` notation is if the property name is not a valid variable name, like `obj['property-name']`.

Comment: Hey, that's pretty good. Here's a link I found that explains it all in some detail: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects